# How can I change the vifm colorscheme?

Tags: filemanager, vifm

I have various themes in `~/.vifm/colors` but when I open vifm and try to change the colourscheme using `:colo <theme>`, it returns:

```
The :colorscheme command is reserved
Press Return to continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it right, but your version of Vifm is very old (it's `0.4`, I guess). Look for Debian at [Downloads section](http://vifm.info/downloads.shtml) of the site. If you don't want to build the latest version from sources, you can use [package from experimental](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/vifm).